# Doom Emacs sudden spaced out font experience after the use of Latex

Tags: emacs, latex

I was doing work on a Latex project and when I closed the emacs at the end of the day and opened it again. It appeared that the font had heavily separated by what I believe are spaces. I am very intrigued about where this sudden change to fonts could have come from, I have been using emacs for about 2 weeks or so, and when I started working on Latex projects today the fonts became like this after closing the client, and then reopening it again.[Picture of the spaced-out font view.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSVxi.png)

Here's the doom emacs Doctor output:
❯ ~/.emacs.d/bin/doom doctor

```
The doctor will see you now...

> Checking your Emacs version...
> Checking for Emacs config conflicts...
> Checking for private config conflicts...
> Checking for stale elc files...
> Checking Doom Emacs...
  ✓ Initialized Doom Emacs 2.0.9
  ✓ Detected 29 modules
  ✓ Detected 118 packages
  > Checking Doom core for irregularities...
    Found font material-design-icons.ttf
    Found font weathericons.ttf
    Found font octicons.ttf
    Found font fontawesome.ttf
    Found font file-icons.ttf
    Found font all-the-icons.ttf
  > Checking for stale elc files in your DOOMDIR...
  > Checking your enabled modules...


Everything seems fine, happy Emacs'ing!
✓ Finished! (0.7816s)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by deleting everything inside .fonts/ directory. Though this also leads to my terminal(Kitty) to malfunction since it looks like it depended on that .fonts/ directory.